# deserialize xml node with unknown child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have some xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <video key="8bJ8OyXI">
      <custom>
        <legacyID>50898311001</legacyID>
      </custom>
      <date>1258497567</date>
      <description>some description</description>
      <duration>486.20</duration>
      <md5>bc89fde37ef103db26b8a9d98065d006</md5>
      <mediatype>video</mediatype>
      <size>99416259</size>
      <sourcetype>file</sourcetype>
      <status>ready</status>
      <views>0</views>
    </video>
 </response>
```

I am using `XmlSerializer` to serialize the xml to class objects, and would prefer to stick with it if possible since everything else works just fine. The node custom is just custom metadata added to the video, and pretty much anything could potentially end up in there (only strings, just a name and value). I used xsd.exe to generate class objects from my xml, which generated a unique class for the `<custom>` tag with just one ulong property for the legacyID value. The thing is, potentially any arbitrary number of values could be there and I can't and don't need to account for them all (but I may need to read particular values later).

Is it possible to set up the Video.Custom property in my class so that the serializer can deserialize those values into say something like a `Dictionary<string, string>`? I don't need type information for those particular values, saving the node names + values are more than enough for my purposes.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.dima.to/blog/?p=197

Comment: You can implement ``IXmlSerializable`` interface.

Comment: @Alexandru that's actually pretty slick but i was hoping to stick with using the XmlSerializer here as it does everything else I need perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle `UnknownElement` event and there deserialize `custom` element to your dictionary

```
serializer.UnknownElement += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Element.LocalName == "custom" && e.ObjectBeingDeserialized is Video)
    {
        Video video = (Video)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;

        if (video.Custom == null)
        {
            video.Custom = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        foreach (XmlElement element in e.Element.OfType<XmlElement>())
        {
            XmlText text = (XmlText)element.FirstChild;
            video.Custom.Add(element.LocalName, text.Value);
        }
    }
};
```